# How to use shared reducers in Redux

Tags: redux, reducers

I have a general question about Reducers. In my application, I have many users (child, parent, and teacher). I  have created a reducer to load tasks from the database for the parent/teacher and in my initial state I have an array "Tasks".

Do I have to create another reducer to load tasks of children from the database and I have to, can I use the same array name "Tasks"?

TasksReducer.js:

```js
const initialState = {
    tasks: [],
    image: null
}

const tasks = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'LOAD_TASKS_FROM_SERVER':
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: action.payload
            };
        case 'ADD_TASK':
            return {
                ...state,
                tasks: [action.payload, ...state.tasks]
            }
            default:
                return state;
    }
};
```

TasksChildReducer.js : (I only have in common the "LOAD_TASKS_FROM_SERVER")

```js
const initialState = {
  tasksChildren: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest way is to have different reducers mounted each in a different key of the root redux state.

So their own keys can be named the same, and you will access them like so

```js
const getChildrenTasks = state => state.children.tasks

const getParentTasks = state => state.parent.tasks

etc.
```

To avoid code duplication, you could also abstract some of the reducer operation in common functions.

Comment: So here, they will have the same array name "tasks"?

Comment: Yes, same key name, but in different objects

Comment: Okay but then, when  I will use it in my js file, how can I know see the difference between these 2 objects..?

Comment: For example, I have this js file for teacher/parent 

const mapStateToProps=state=>{
  return{
    tasks:state.tasks
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps=dispatch=>{
  return{
    loadTasks:tasks=> dispatch({type:'LOAD_TASKS_FROM_SERVER',payload:tasks}),
    addTask:task=>dispatch({type:'ADD_TASK',payload:task}),
  }
}


But how can I see the difference between this js file and the js file for children?